# 2-way binding for radio buttons in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

i am kind of stuck here, i am new to angular js.

I have a form having number of questions. These questions are loading with angularjs.

html for form is

```
<form ng-controller="controller" ng-submit="submitFirstQuiz()">
<div ng-repeat = "question in quiz.questions">
{{question}}
<label data-ng-repeat="choice in quiz.choices" style="float:left;">
    <input name="{{question}}" type="radio" value="{{choice}}"/>
</label>
<br/>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
</ng-form>
```

and my js is

```
'use strict';

var QuizModule = angular.module('quiz');

QuizModule.controller('PersonalityQuizCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.quiz = {
            questions: ["q1","q2","q3"],
            choices: ["5","4","3","2","1"]
        };

    $scope.submitFirstQuiz = function(){
        console.debug("how to print selected choices");
    };

});
```

The above code is generating my form as i want. Now how can i get the selected values of the radio buttons, in other word how can i submit the form with selected value. I don't how to bind the result data. Kindly help me, i shall be thankful.
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**:

```
<input name="{{question}}" ng-click="radioSelected(choice, question)" 
type="radio" value="{{choice}}"/>
```

**JS**:

```
'use strict';

var QuizModule = angular.module('quiz');

QuizModule.controller('PersonalityQuizCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.quiz = {
            questions: ["q1","q2","q3"],
            choices: ["5","4","3","2","1"]
        };

    $scope.selectedChoices = {};

    $scope.radioSelected = function(choice, question){        
        $scope.selectedChoices[question] = choice;
    }
    $scope.submitFirstQuiz = function(){
        console.log($scope.selectedChoices);
    };

});
```

Comment: now all respective buttons for all questions are getting selected, i have added the screen shot. for example. if i select first choice for question 1, choice one is automatically selected for all questions.